# systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Module - Failed to find module 'acpiphp'

Tags: 16.04, kernel, bootloader

I don't know why this error:

```
   systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-04-28 02:18:40 UTC; 30s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 1096 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1096 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 28 02:18:40 myuser systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Apr 28 02:18:40 myuser systemd-modules-load[1096]: Failed to find module 'acpiphp'
Apr 28 02:18:40 myuser systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1
Apr 28 02:18:40 myuser systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
Apr 28 02:18:40 myuser systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 28 02:18:40 myuser systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I do crazy thins like:

```
sudo apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt full-upgrade -f
sudo apt -f install
```

But still error. I find nothing on Google.

Answer (score 0):

It's a virtualbox or KVM VM?

Try to blacklist this module

```
echo "blacklist acpiphp" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

then reboot

Comment: This is a KVM. KERNEL 4.4.0-108-generic

Nothing has changed, error still.

Comment: Well, I don't know then. I'm not sure about it but you can try to do reverse: remove blacklist and use `insmod acpiphp` or add `acpiphp` to /etc/modules. If this won't help maybe you're missing acpi packages? What about `apt-get install acpid acpi acpi-call-dkms`